# Could not reserve enough space for object heap - Alfresco build from source

Tags: java, maven, ant, alfresco

I am trying to build Alfresco from source and I am following the instructions from [this](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SVN_Development_Environment) link. But whenever I try to execute below command:

```
ant build-tomcat
```

I am getting below error:

```
[mkdir] Created dir: E:\Pradeep\Alfresco\Alfresco   Source\root\projects\core\build\classes
[javac] Compiling 159 source files to E:\Pradeep\Alfresco\Alfresco   Source\root\projects\core\build\classes
[javac] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[javac] Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
[javac] Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[javac] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

I tried setting heap size using following environment variable:

```
JAVA_OPTS = -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

I played with various values like 1333M, 1024M, 64M etc. But still I get same error. As an alternative I tried to execute using maven also by `mvn clean install`, but even that won't run, I get following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project alfresco-core: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.ma
>   erminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?

**Edit**: For Maven surefire plugin, this is the memory configuration I have:

> -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Duser.language=en -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

My system configuration is: Windows 7 32 Bit, Dual Core, 4GB RAM.

Can anyone kindly help me how do I resolve this error?

Comment: You won't be able to reserve 2Gb of memory on 32-bit system. Try changing surefire config to `-Xmx1G`. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing heap size for maven build by

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1500m"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried. But I am getting same error.

Comment: it crashes JVM while executing tests (from sure fire plugin), do you want to run test cases as a part of build if yes post your surefire plugin configuration from pom.xml

Comment: try investigating why it fails to execute tests and fix the code/increase memory provided to surefire